# How can I show all dynamic metrics with grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm usign prometheus with grafana.

I send dynamic counters. The counters are ended with a pattern, for example "_graph".

How can I show in a graph all the metrics which ends with "_graph"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In grafana query user this:

```
{__name__=~".+_graph"}
```

This will show all the metrics with `_graph` suffix.

Probably you want to use sth like

```
rate({__name__=~".+_graph"}[5m])
```

if these are counters.

Comment: That second query will fail, this sounds like a case for labels but barring that https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names.

Comment: Yup, you're totally right. If there was no requirement to have range specification preceded by metric selector than rate requirement for single name could be appeased by `lable_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the Explore (compass); `Metric Browser` has drop down where we can see all the metric names.

[image]